# make sort - Built-in Function

Tags: unix, compiler-construction, makefile

I want to sort from the makefile the lines in a txt file. I found this sort function which is a make function (Built-in Functions).

```
$(sort list)
```

My idea:

```
$(UNSORT) = $(cat input.txt)
$(SORTED) = $(sort $(UNSORT))
@echo $(SORTED) >output.txt
```

.. but this work not :S

Can anyone Help?

Comment: What about whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

just call sort command this way

```
sort text.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This is a make built in function? This not removing the duplicate words…

This is an example from make tutorial:

$(sort foo bar lose)

This works fine.

Comment: No, sort is a standard command line program. If you also need to remove duplicates you can use "cat input.txt | sort | uniq > output.txt"

Comment: I may use only this make build in functions.

Comment: Alexeyss: note that the `sort` program sorts _line by line_.  The make `$(sort ...)` function sorts _word by word_.  So (depending on the format of the input.txt file) they may not be the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should not surround a variable name with `$()` during an assignment. So the first two assignment statements should be of the form `VARIABLE = some_value`

The second issue is with the invocation of `cat`. To run any shell command, we must use make's built-in function `$(shell ...)`. A simple `$(cat ...)` won't do.

With these corrections in place, the script runs fine:

```
UNSORT = $(shell cat input.txt)
SORTED = $(sort $(UNSORT))

all:
    @echo $(SORTED) > output.txt
```